# KEYWORD_SET in IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am new to IDL and find the `KEYWORD_SET` difficult to grasp. I understand that it is a go no go switch. I think its the knocking on and off part that I am having difficulty with. I have written a small program to master this as such

```
Pro get_this_done, keyword1 = keyword1 

WW=[3,6,8]

PRINT,'WW'
print,WW

y= WW*3
IF KEYWORD_Set(keyword1) Then BEGIN  
   print,'y'
   print,y

ENDIF
Return
END
```

`WW` prints but `print, y` is restricted by the keyword. How do I knock off the keyword to allow `y` to print.
Silly little question, but if somebody can indulge me, it would be great.

Comment: this is a very good discussion about the topic http://www.idlcoyote.com/tips/keyword_check.html

Answer (score 1):

After compiling the routine, type something like

```
get_this_done,KEYWORD1=1b
```

where the `b` after the one sets the numeric value to a `BYTE` type integer (also equivalent to `TRUE`).  That should cause the y-variable to be printed to the screen.

The [KEYWORD_SET](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/keyword_set.html) function will return a `TRUE` for lots of different types of inputs that are basically either defined or not zero.  The [IF](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/if___then___else.html) loop executes when the argument is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Keywords are simply passed as arguments to the function:

```
get_this_done, KEYWORD1='whatever'
```

or also

```
get_this_done, /KEYWORD1
```

which will give KEYWORD1 the INT value of 1 inside the function. Inside the function KEYWORD_SET will return 1 (TRUE) when the keyword was passed any kind of value - no matter whether it makes sense or not.

Thus as a side note to the question: It often is advisable to NOT use `KEYWORD_SET`, but instead resort to a type query:

```
IF SIZE(variable, /TNAME) EQ 'UNDEFINED' THEN $
  variable = 'default value'
```

It has the advantage that you can actually check for the correct type of the keyword and handle unexpected or even different variable types:

```
IF SIZE(variable, /TNAME) NE 'LONG' THEN BEGIN
  IF SIZE(variable, /TNAME) EQ 'STRING' THEN $
    PRINT, "We need a number here... sure that the cast to LONG works?"
  variable = LONG(variable)
ENDIF
```

Comment: The second one listed doesn't seem to me a correct use. KEYWORD_SET is usually employed to check the value of a flag and e.g. it should never be used to set default values for a variable (as I think is in this example).  Also, more important, it shouldn't be checked for undefined. The use case in the question is a perfect example, here the flag is used to decide if printing an output or not. 

procedure get_this_done can be called by another procedure that sets the flag to 1 and leaves the option to disable it by calling with 0. This is expected behavior that fails if checked with undefined.

Comment: I think you mis-understand my answer. My point is: it's good to use as binary flag. But if you want to check whether a variable was passed and you care about the value - and passed as the right type - then keyword_set is not of much use

Comment: it is possible, because I didn't understand where `variable` came from, and found it misleading. Thanks for specifying.